# How to update a package in test environment after I changed it in development environment?

Tags: managed-package, package, record, custom-metadata

How to update a package in test environment after I changed it in development environment?

After creating a package I forgot to add a few records of a specific Custom Metadata Type. Now I went to the package manager and added all the necessary records and would like to see those records in the test org where the package was installed.

All of the above is about a managed package.

According to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm) Custom Metadata Records are Upgradeable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming the installed version was already a Release version, simply upload the new version as a new Release version, and install it in the test environment. The changes will be applied as an upgrade. If the already installed version is Beta, however, you'd have to uninstall the previous version before installing the new version.